# guardar valores en tabla mysql zerofill con c #

Tags: c#, mysql

```
    1   SucursalPrimaria    int(3)      UNSIGNED ZEROFILL
```

tengo una tabla con consecutivo zerofill para que me guarde los ceros a la izquierda pero cuando capturo ese dato en c# y le sumo 1 y quiero volver a guardar el siguiente me lo deja en 0, es decir leo el 000 y quiero guardar el 001, luego el 002 pero no me los incrementa. tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    public void obtenerconsecutivo()
    {
        miconsecutivo = 0;
        try
        {
            using (var mysql = new mysqlconect())
            {
                mysql.conexion2();
                mysql.cadenasql = "select Consecutivo from consecutivo";
                mysql.comando = new MySqlCommand(mysql.cadenasql, 
              mysql.con);
                mysql.comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                using (var lee = mysql.comando.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (lee.Read())
                    {

                        misucursal = 1;
                        miterminal = 1;
                        mitipo = 1;
                        capturaconsecutivo = lee["Consecutivo"].ToString();

                    }
                }
                mysql.rol();
                mysql.Dispose();

                miconsecutivo = Int32.Parse(capturaconsecutivo)+1;
                MessageBox.Show(miconsecutivo.ToString("D10"));

                using (var mysql2 = new mysqlconect())
                {
                    mysql2.conexion2();
                    mysql2.cadenasql = "INSERT INTO 
               `consecutivo`(`Sucursal`, `Terminal`, `Tipo`, `Consecutivo`) 
                VALUES ('@sucursal','@terminal','@tipo','@consecutivo')";
                    mysql2.comando = new MySqlCommand(mysql2.cadenasql, 
                  mysql2.con);



          mysql2.comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sucursal",misucursal);

          mysql2.comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@terminal",miterminal);
                    mysql2.comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo",  
           mitipo);

       mysql2.comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@consecutivo",miconsecutivo);
                    mysql2.comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    mysql2.rol();
                    mysql2.Dispose();


                }

                label1.Text =string.Concat(misucursal.ToString("D3") , 
                miterminal.ToString("D5") , mitipo.ToString("D2") , 
                 miconsecutivo.ToString("D10"));


            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException mys)
        {
            mensajes.mensaje2(mys);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            mensajes.mensaje1(e);
        }



         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es que en el método obtenerconsecutivo haces muchas cosas, deberías encapsular tus métodos de acuerdo a la función que realizas, ej:

**metodo obtenerConsecutivo:**

```
    private static int ObtenerConsecutivo()
    {
        Int32 newConsecutivo = 0;
        var cadenaSql = @"SELECT Consecutivo FROM consecutivo";


        using (var mysql = new mysqlconect())
        {

            mysql.comando = new MySqlCommand(cadenaSql, mysql.con);

            try
            {
                newConsecutivo = (Int32)mysql.comando.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (MySqlException mys)
            {
                mensajes.mensaje2(mys);
            }
        }
        return (int)newConsecutivo;

    }
```

Como se puede obervar, en este método solo hago una cosa: obtener el Numero consecutivo.

por otro lado, tengo la sospecha que el campo en la tabla que gestiona tu numero consecutivo deberia ser un campo AUTO_INCREMENT, así te evitas tener que estar sumandole uno manualmente por código.

Siguiendo con el ejemplo de tu código, tu método de **insertar** te quedaría así:

```
private void Insert(string nombre, string direccion, DateTime fechaNacimiento)
{
    mysql2.cadenasql = @"INSERT INTO 
                       `consecutivo`(`Sucursal`, `Terminal`, `Tipo`, `Consecutivo`) 
                        VALUES ('?sucursal','?terminal','?tipo','?consecutivo')";


    using (var mysql2 = new mysqlconect())
    {
        mysql2.conexion2();

        int newConsecutivo = ObtenerConsecutivo() + 1;

        mysql2.comando = new MySqlCommand(mysql2.cadenasql, mysql2.con);
        mysql2.comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?sucursal", misucursal);

        mysql2.comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?terminal", miterminal);
        mysql2.comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?tipo",mitipo);

        mysql2.comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?consecutivo", newConsecutivo);

        int rowsAffected = mysql2.comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rowsAffected > 0)
        {
            label1.Text = string.Concat(misucursal.ToString("D3"),
            miterminal.ToString("D5"), mitipo.ToString("D2"),
            miconsecutivo = newConsecutivo.ToString("D10"));
        }

        mysql2.rol();
        mysql2.Dispose();

    }
}
```